# I receive the following message when i run the program in selenium. Java version used is 9.0.1

Tags: java, selenium

Error:(4, 15) java: package org.omg.CORBA is not visible
  (package org.omg.CORBA is declared in module java.corba, which is not in the module graph)

It's working fine in java 8

Comment: Related: [*Replacements for deprecated JPMS modules with Java EE APIs*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48204141/642706)

Answer (score 0):

Look here https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-9-migration-guide/ 
Section 'Dependencies On Java EE Modules' 
Quotation from there:

> There’s a lot of code in Java SE that’s actually Java EE related. It
>   ended up in these six modules:   java.corba with javax.activity,
>   javax.rmi, javax.rmi.CORBA, and **org.omg.*** packages  For various
>   compatibility reasons (one of them being split packages, which we will
>   look at next), code on the class path does not see these modules by
>   default, which leads to compile or run time errors...
>
> error: XXX is not visible 
>       (package XXX is declared in module XXX,
>           which is not in the module graph)

And solution also is described there. Looks like your problem.