# Unable to unmarshall metro config file from location occurs on remote debian based server, but not locally on windows 10

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-rs, jax-ws

Recently I had to migrate SOAP based WS from java 8 to 11, I added all necessery jars and finally i was able to run it locally(windows 10), but on remote server based on debian (4.19.194-4) i'm getting java.lang.InternalError: MASM0010: Unable to unmarshall metro config file from location [ jar:file:/web/WEB-INF/lib/rt-2.3.1.jar!/META-INF/jaxws-tubes-default.xml ].

I have same versions of java locally and on server, also i granted all privileges to WEB-INF/lib directory.

Is there any reason why I'm getting this error only on server version?

Full stacktrace:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: MASM0010: Unable to unmarshall metro config file from location [ jar:file:/web/WEB-INF/lib/rt-2.3.1.jar!/META-INF/jaxws-tubes-default.xml ]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.MetroConfigLoader.loadMetroConfig(MetroConfigLoader.java:264)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.MetroConfigLoader.init(MetroConfigLoader.java:147)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.MetroConfigLoader.<init>(MetroConfigLoader.java:121)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblyController.getTubeCreators(TubelineAssemblyController.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.MetroTubelineAssembler.createClient(MetroTubelineAssembler.java:118)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.createPipeline(Stub.java:343)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:310)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:243)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:258)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.<init>(SEIStub.java:98)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getStubHandler(WSServiceDelegate.java:821)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createEndpointIFBaseProxy(WSServiceDelegate.java:810)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:452)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:420)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:211)
    at org.tempuri.TerytWs1.getCustom(TerytWs1.java:84)
    at path.to.controller.zaladujDaneTerytAction(controller.java:351)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Unable to locate jaxb.properties for package com.sun.xml.ws.runtime.config
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.searchcontextPath(ContextFinder.java:226)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:170)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:311)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:268)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.MetroConfigLoader.createJAXBContext(MetroConfigLoader.java:298)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.MetroConfigLoader.loadMetroConfig(MetroConfigLoader.java:256)
    ... 56 more
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: For anyone facing the same issue. In my case the problem was related with ComputableFuture. Here is link to the solution that resolved my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51518781/jaxb-not-available-on-tomcat-9-and-java-9-10/61012531#61012531