# Looking for jar that defines javax.activity (no longer provided by java.corba module as per JEP 320)

Tags: java, corba, java-module, java-11

I have a follow-up question in connection to [Replacements for deprecated JPMS modules with Java EE APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204141/replacements-for-deprecated-jpms-modules-with-java-ee-apis), in particular the replacement of the java.corba module and its javax.activity package.

I am looking for a jar file that provides javax.activity.

I see javax.rmi, javax.rmi.CORBA, and org.omg.* provided by glassfish-corba-omgapi-4.2.0-b004.jar, but I'm unable to locate a jar file that defines javax.activity. Is there any?

I did find openjdk-orb-8.1.2.Final.jar providing it, but it get an error when I try to use it as an automatic module:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for /Users/jluehe/blt/app/main/core/sfdc/modules_jdk_11-ea_x64/modules/openjdk-orb-8.1.2.Final.jar
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Any hints appreciated. Thanks!