# JDK 11: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/handler/soap/SOAPHandler

Tags: java

We are migrating to openjdk 11 from jdk 8. Some of our projects that uses soap to call third party apis are failing with error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/handler/soap/SOAPHandler
```

After doing some research, I tried by adding dependencies :

[
**references:**

- [How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j)
- [Replacements for deprecated JPMS modules with Java EE APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204141/replacements-for-deprecated-jpms-modules-with-java-ee-apis)

]

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.xml.soap-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Did not work. may I get an idea on the alternatives?

Comment: Perhaps show a snippet of your code that provokes the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. Something like a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It looks like you forgot to include [jaxws-api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.ws/jaxws-api/2.2).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Switch to `jakarta.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler` and include [`jakarta.xml.ws-api`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.xml.ws/jakarta.xml.ws-api) in your dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are still on versions that use `javax` instead of `jakarta`, include [`jaxws-api`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.ws/jaxws-api) in your dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Jakarta EE 9, which moved the API namespace from `javax` to `jakarta`, was [released on December 8, 2020](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_EE#History) which happens to fall between the [releases of Java 15 and Java 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Release_table), but it will really depend more on your other dependencies than the version of Java you're using.

Comment: If you are using Microsoft EWS Library and you get the same exception this dependency helps resolve the issue.

Answer (score 38):

The `javax` APIs were transitioned to `Jakarta`, so in 2020 the proper dependency is the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Here's an article summarizing what happened:
[Java Magazine - Transition from Java EE to Jakarta EE](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/transition-from-java-ee-to-jakarta-ee?source=:em:nw:mt::RC_WWMK190726P00001:NSL400052571)

And here's a [very useful table with mappings](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jakarta_EE_Maven_Coordinates) between the old artifacts and the new one.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is the first result on google, my issue was due to having a jar, that required `javax.xml.ws` classes, on the Tomcat common folder `/usr/local/tomcat/lib`.

The [Tomcat classloader hierarchy](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) is

```
      Bootstrap
          |
       System
          |
       Common
       /     \
  Webapp1   Webapp2 ...
```

On Java 8 the common classloader can load these classes since they are on Java JRE itself, but on Java 11, the `javax.xml.ws` classes are on Webapp1, and the Tomcat common classloader can not load these.

For me, the solution was to no longer deploy the jar into the Tomcat common lib folder.