# Getting a ClassNotFoundException when starting Tomcat 9 after upgrading to Java 11

Tags: java, tomcat

Maintaining an old application written in Netbeans and trying to currently update it to Java 11. I was able to solve some initial problems when I asked a previous question and got directed to this:

[Replacements for deprecated JPMS modules with Java EE APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204141/replacements-for-deprecated-jpms-modules-with-java-ee-apis)

I added those modules as Jar libraries to the project and it got rid of compile errors. Now I am stuck with one last exception being thrown when Tomcat starts.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jws.WebService
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1275)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1109)
```

I'm pretty sure this should be included in this jar file `jaxws-api-2.3.0.jar` since other errors in the localhost log files disappeared after adding this jar.

Are there other settings / options I may need to add, perhaps something to do with modules, in order for Tomcat to find this class?

Comment: The Tomcat class path and the Netbeans class path are different. Make sure the jars are compiled with the project so that they are available on the Tomcat server at start up

Comment: I checked the generated Jar which is placed in the /usr/local/tomcat/webapps directory and they contain the Jar files in the /WEB-INF/lib folder of the war file. Do I just need to add that classpath to Tomcat?

Comment: @AK47 and how do you make sure that they are compiled? Please provide a complete answer :(

Comment: @iSpain17 I guess you compile them all into a .WAR file and deploy your .WAR file to Tomcat