# Make sure all referenced classes are on classpath: interface javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter

Tags: spring, java-11, spring-framework-beans

I have an xml bean that is been (xmlProvider) instantiated from a class :
class ContextResolver implements ContextResolver
We are upgrading from java 8 to java 11 and use gradle 5.1.
In addition we have upgraded from spring 4.2.7 to 5.1.4

On run time I get the following exception.
Does anyone have any input on why this exception comes up

```
2019-02-11 08:54:31,643 ERROR localhost-startStop-1 - [EVENT UNSPECIFIED null -> /Frameworks/org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ClientServiceServer': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'xmlProvider' while setting bean property 'providers' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xmlProvider' defined in class path resource [rest-beans.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.InternalError: 
Error occured while invoking reflection on target classes. Make sure all referenced classes are on classpath: interface javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter 
Exception: null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:401)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:159)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1648)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1400)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:400)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4900)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5363)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:755)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:973)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1850)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xmlProvider' defined in class path resource [rest-beans.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.InternalError: 
Error occured while invoking reflection on target classes. Make sure all referenced classes are on classpath: interface javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter 
Exception: null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: 
Error occured while invoking reflection on target classes. Make sure all referenced classes are on classpath: interface javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter 
Exception: null
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.getClassValue(RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.java:143)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.getClassValue(RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.java:57)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.PropertyInfoImpl.isApplicable(PropertyInfoImpl.java:216)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.PropertyInfoImpl.getApplicableAdapter(PropertyInfoImpl.java:227)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.PropertyInfoImpl.<init>(PropertyInfoImpl.java:126)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ERPropertyInfoImpl.<init>(ERPropertyInfoImpl.java:57)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl.<init>(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:100)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeElementPropertyInfoImpl.<init>(RuntimeElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:63)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.createElementProperty(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:175)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.addProperty(ClassInfoImpl.java:882)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.findFieldProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:408)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.getProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:311)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.getProperties(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:186)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:261)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:103)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:227)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:98)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:375)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.calcRef(TypeRefImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.getTarget(TypeRefImpl.java:73)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:62)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:55)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:78)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:76)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:371)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:275)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:103)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:227)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:98)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:375)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:390)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:465)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:303)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:139)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1156)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:165)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:251)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:240)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:363)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:691)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:632)
    at no.io..ws.ContextResolver.initializeJaxbContext(ContextResolver.java:57)
    at no.io..ws.ContextResolver.<clinit>(ContextResolver.java:44)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1262)
    ... 38 more
```

Rest

Comment: Looks like a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/48204141

Comment: The problem seems to be that the jaxb-api jar file aren't added to my war file, so I get a runtime exception. How can I force jaxb-api.jar into my warfile?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that, but it would be good if you [edit] the question to refine it based on your debugging. That could help others give you an answer.