# Is apache-camel source code buildable in open-jdk-11?

Tags: java, build, apache-camel

When building apache-camel with openJDK-11. There are a lot of missing dependencies like
* jaxb
* annotation
* ...

How to build apache-camel source code with openJDK? 
Officially there is no documentation on how to build using openJDK; Is there is any way to force build it?

I have tried adding jaxb implementation for server like "org.eclipse.persistence.moxy" but the same wasn't picked up properly :(

I have restricted the build env to be only open source; hence using openJDK as the base for development.

Comment: All things considered, a lot has changed with the newer versions of Java, so I'm not *that* surprised that it wouldn't build today with OpenJDK 11...Camel's a **big** project and there's a lot of possibility for breakage with the fact that several previously bundled dependencies aren't there when you're compiling today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this article https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-11-migration-guide/ several packages have been removed from JDK 11.

In particular the section called Migrating From Java 8 To Java 11 shed some light on how to deal with this.

In short the following packages were removed:

- The JavaBeans Activation Framework (JAF) in javax.activation CORBA in the packages javax.activity, javax.rmi, javax.rmi.CORBA, and org.omg.*
- The Java Transaction API (JTA) in the package javax.transaction
- JAXB in the packages javax.xml.bind.*
- JAX-WS in the packages javax.jws, javax.jws.soap, javax.xml.soap, and javax.xml.ws.*
- Commons Annotation in the package javax.annotation

To fix this:

Add third-party dependencies that contain the classes you need. The easiest way to do that is to stick to the reference implementations (given as Maven coordinates without version – use the most current ones):

- JAF: with com.sun.activation:javax.activation
- CORBA: there is currently no artifact for this
- JTA: javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api
- JAXB: com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl
- JAX-WS: com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri
- Commons Annotation: javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api

You can also view some more information [using this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204141/replacements-for-deprecated-jpms-modules-with-java-ee-apis/48204154#48204154)