# JDK 11 with JAXB and JAXWS works with Eclipse but not IntelliJ

Tags: eclipse, jaxb, intellij-14

I am converting an application that uses JAXB and JAX-WS from JDK 8 to JDK 11. The code runs when I use Eclipse IDE but exactly the same code fails with IntelliJ IDEA

I have created a Maven project using both Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA. The problems of finding a working combination of Maven resources has been described in another question. [JDK 11 with JAXB and JAXWS problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56105992/jdk-11-with-jaxb-and-jaxws-problems) 
The code builds without error in both environments. I have tried creating the IntelliJ IDEA project as a Maven project as well as a standard IDEA project

part of pom.xl

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
  <version>11.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
  <version>11.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- JAXWS for Java 11 -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

module-info.java

```
module org.openfx.gustfx {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires transitive javafx.graphics;
    requires java.xml.bind;
    requires java.xml.ws;
    requires javax.jws;

    opens com.agile.ws.schema.common.v1.jaxws to javafx.fxml;
    opens org.openfx.gustfx to javafx.fxml;
    exports org.openfx.gustfx;
}
```

When the code is run from Eclipse, there are no errors.
Running the same code from IntelliJ IDE results in this error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl
```

Searching through the jar files confirms that ProviderImpl.class is now located  in com.sun.ws.spi not in com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi   This does not cause a problem with eclipse but IDEA reports the ClassNotFoundException

Therefore, my question "How does eclipse resolve this problem while IntelliJ does not ?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from Roman Shevchenko at IntelliJ, I have solved this problem using the following pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.jws-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

and module-info.java

```
requires java.xml.ws;
requires java.xml.bind;
requires javax.jws;
```