# Error while importing javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException in java class

Tags: java, maven, import

while importing `javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException;` in java file, I am getting compilation error

> cannot resolve symbol ws.

I have cleaned and installed dependencies mentioned in POM.xml

Comment: it is showing package javax.xml.ws does not exist

Comment: Please add your pom.xml and Java code.

Comment: As mentionned, we need your pom.xml to help you.
You should have something like this in order to fix the import
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

Either it is not correctly stated in your `pom.xml`. Or the project you're trying to import is meant for JDK 8 which still include the `JAX-WS` API, and you're using JDK 8+ compiler. See [Replacements for deprecated JPMS modules with Java EE APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204141/replacements-for-deprecated-jpms-modules-with-java-ee-apis/48204154#48204154).

Edit: add reference.

Answer (score 0):

Add webservices-api.jar in project classpath and clean your project.