# How to resolve JAXB classpath issues on Java 12

Tags: gradle, jaxb, java-11, java-12

Im porting application using JAXB to JDK 11/12 but am completely lost when trying to fix those JAXB classpath issues. I have googled and read basically everything related to this so Im aware of the changes made in Java11, i.e. removal of JAXB from JDK ... However in that case I would assume a trivial fix consisting of adding api and impl JARs on classpath. But this is not working and despite I have those JARs on classpath Im still getting the known exception, despite using 2.3.2 JAXB:

> javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
>      - with linked exception:
>     [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]

even if I see the class is in different package and I instruct to use correct package via system variable it does not work either:

gradle -Djavax.xml.bind.context.factory=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory build

> javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
>      - with linked exception:
>     [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory]

Does anyone have clue how to resolve this? I dont want to play with manifest files etc. It should be possible to just place the right JARs on classpath and that is it, or not?

Summary here but unable to get it working:
http://www.descher.at/descher-vu/2019/01/java-11-jaxb-and-osgi/

Update, dependencies used in Gradle:
- jaxb-xjc has jaxb-runtime (impl.) as transitive dependency. I see it is picked by Gradle but still the same error.

```
classpath "com.sun.activation:javax.activation:1.2.0"
classpath "jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.2"
classpath "org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-xjc:2.3.2"
classpath"org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1"
```

> [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Resolve jaxb-runtime.jar (org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.2)' completed
>
> [org.gradle.internal.component.model.ComponentAttributeMatcher] Selected match org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.2 configuration runtime from candidates [org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.2 configuration runtime] for {org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.jvm.version=12, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}

This is output of "gradle dependencies" and all the JAXB jars are there, still classpath error is being thrown. The JAR file jaxb-runtime from Glassfish for sure has this ContextFactory class.

```
runtimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'main'.
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2 -> 2.1.0.RELEASE
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.11.1
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|    |    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.11.1
|    |    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.11.1
|    |         \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.11.1
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.11.1 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jul:2.11.1
|    |    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.11.1
|    \--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.25
|         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
+--- org.projectlombok:lombok -> 1.18.2
+--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3 -> 3.8.1
+--- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4 -> 4.4
+--- com.google.guava:guava -> 23.0
|    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9
|    +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.0.18
|    +--- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:1.1
|    \--- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:1.14
+--- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core -> 2.0.1
+--- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.2
|    +--- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.2
|    |    \--- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1
|    +--- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:2.3.2
|    +--- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:3.0.8
|    |    \--- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1
|    +--- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:1.8.1
|    |    +--- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1
|    |    \--- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.2 (*)
|    +--- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:1.2.16
|    \--- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.1
\--- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1
     +--- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0 -> 2.3.1
     |    \--- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:1.2.0
     +--- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:2.3.0.1 -> 2.3.2
     \--- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:3.0.5 -> 3.0.8 (*)
```

Comment: Instead of enabling the deprecated javax.xml.bind module you should simply add the required libraries as dependency to your project: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57643763/150978

Comment: I believe I have these dependencies, but not able to get rid of the error.

Comment: Post updated with detailed dependency information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacements for deprecated JPMS modules with Java EE APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204141/replacements-for-deprecated-jpms-modules-with-java-ee-apis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From some reason I had no luck with Glassfish JARs, but those original Sun/Oracle dependencies worked.

Comment: I'm using `<dependency><groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId><artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId><version>2.3.0</version></dependency>
  <dependency><groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId><artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId><version>2.3.0</version></dependency>`