# Running Java 8 jar when only Java 11 JRE is available

Tags: java, java-11

I have a third-party executable jar file which I don't have access to the source code of. It was compiled with Java 8 and it uses some javax packages for XML processing. These are in Java EE and have been removed from recent versions of Java SE.

I want to run this third-party jar file on a host machine that I don't have control over. It has Java 11 installed and I'm not allowed to install Java 8 on it.

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48204154/638028) which says that the way to solve this issue is to rebuild the application with additional dependencies to replace the Java EE packages that were removed from the Java 11 jre. Unfortunately, I can't use that answer because I don't have access to the source code. Can I instead use a `-classpath` argument to the `java -jar` command to solve this?

Comment: The answer you’ve linked describes where you can get the classes (or jars) from. You don’t need to rebuild your application. You only need to build the library which provides the classes (I don’t know which of the projects listed in the answer you need), then you can add the jar file(s) to your classpath. Since `javax.…` is not a reserved package name in the security model, this works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is a runnable jar, then it has a `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file that sets up the classpath.

You don't need the source code. Just unjar the jar file, add extra entries for the required additional third-party jars to the `Class-Path` in the `MANIFEST.MF` file, and jar it back up.

Then ship the jar file together with the additional third-party jars.

---

**Example**

Say your `foo.jar` file uses JAF (java.activation), i.e. it needs `javax.activation-1.2.0.jar` added to the classpath.

Edit the `MANIFEST.MF` file and add `javax.activation-1.2.0.jar` to the end of the `Class-Path` value, separated from existing values with a space. If there is no `Class-Path`, add it:

```
Class-Path: javax.activation-1.2.0.jar
```

Then ship the updated `foo.jar` and the new `javax.activation-1.2.0.jar` file, to be placed in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

`java -jar` does not allow to set custom classpath.

Comment: Whilst your comment is true, it does not provide a solution to the question.

Comment: Answer is true, but the classpath can be replaced, by not using `-jar`, so the answer is really not that useful.

Comment: A workaround is a solution too. Maybe not an elegant one, but it is a solution. Simply saying "cannot be done" when a workaround is available is misleading.