# JAXB and Java 11 module-info.java

Tags: java, jaxb, java-11, java-module

My environment:

```
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.2.9.1 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.2.9.1 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And a simple program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);

    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

    Person person = new Person(1L, "Thomas");
    marshaller.marshal(person, System.out);
}
```

At this point, everything **works just fine**.

Then I add ***module-info.java***:

```
module com.thanh {
    requires java.xml;
    requires java.xml.bind;

    opens com.thanh;

    exports com.thanh;
}
```

And exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
    at java.xml.bind/javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:278)
    at java.xml.bind/javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:421)
    at java.xml.bind/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721)
    at java.xml.bind/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662)
    at com.thanh/com.thanh.App.main(App.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.xml.bind/javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:122)
    at java.xml.bind/javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:155)
    at java.xml.bind/javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:276)
    ... 4 more
```

How can I get JAXB work with Java 11 module?

I need module for my JavaFX project.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48204154/706317)? Try to use `jakarta.xml.bind-api` and `jaxb-runtime` instead.

Comment: Thank you @ZhekaKozlov , I have replaced dependencies as you suggested and now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [JAXB official page](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jaxb-ri/), you should use these dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: `com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl` [has been deprecated](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl). The new runtime is `org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime`.

Comment: Where can I find the xml file? I could not find it anywhere for the software I am using (nifi registry)