# Base64 error: java.lang.NullPointerException at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(DatatypeConverter.java:296)

Tags: java, encoding, base64, apache-commons

I get the error by running this simple main method:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        byte[] result =
                DatatypeConverter
                        .parseBase64Binary("some key");
    }
}
```

The answers I've managed to find are back from 2014 and advise to use Java 1.6, while I use Java 11.

Comment: JAXB has been removed from Java 11, possibly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48204154/13279831) may help you to check for the proper migration.

Comment: Unable to reproduce the error using Java 11 (OpenJDK) and [this JAXB 2.3.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1) JAR.

Comment: @andrewjames Thank you! I added that dependency to my `pom.xml` and now it works!