# Java 8 to Java 11 migration issues with JAXB API

Tags: spring-boot, maven, java-8, jaxb, java-11

We are in process of migrating our projects from Java 8 to Java 11. One of the APIs is dependent on a library that utilizes JAXB. As we know JAXB was removed from JAVA 11 we started to include the JAXB dependencies in the POM of the library.

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.xml.bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api -->
  <!-- API -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- Runtime -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

All works fine when we run the API project with

> mvn spring-boot:run

However when the API is deployed in QA servers and is started using a start script with -

> java -jar Sample-api-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

The API throws the following error when invoking the library that is dependent on JAXB -

```
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
```

- with linked exception:

> ```
>  [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
>       at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:269)
>       at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:412)
>       at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721)
>       at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662)
>       at com.eoriginal.ecore.client.documents.SearchDocumentHistoryAPI$RequestParameters.toMap(SearchDocumentHistoryAPI.java:344)
>       ... 14 more
>     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>       at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
>       at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:122)
>       at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:155)
>       at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:267)
> ```
>
> UPDATE :
> I added the Maven Shade plugin to generate the JAR with all the dependencies but when the line of code is executed to create the JAXBContext the error still persists -
> JAXBContext jaxbc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[]{Abc.class});
> [image]

Comment: Got this working? Struggling with the same behavior in my application...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacements for deprecated JPMS modules with Java EE APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204141/replacements-for-deprecated-jpms-modules-with-java-ee-apis)

Answer (score 0):

JAXB needs `javax.activation` module, which became [`jakarta.activation`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.activation/jakarta.activation-api/2.0.0) after rebranding to JakartaEE. Inlcuding this dependency should help:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am still facing the issue - Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath. With the following dependencies in my POM -

Comment: I am also seeing that when I build the library in Java I dont see any of the dependencies in the external libraries. Could that be a problem and I have to manually bundle the JAXB libraries.

Comment: Dependency to activation-api version 1.2.1 (not 2.0.0) is already added to the jaxb-runtime:2.3.2. See https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency to POM:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```