# Introducing Java 9 modules to a monolithic Spring Tomcat project

Tags: java, spring, maven, java-platform-module-system

I have a standard monolithic Spring Java project which gets packaged as a war (with our code in class files within the war, not in a single jar) and deployed into a Tomcat. We have different Spring profiles allowing the same war to be deployed on different instances for different use cases. The project is built with Maven with all source in `src/main/java`.

As part of the work to move away from the legacy structure, we are hoping to start using Java modules for *new* code, and over time refactor stuff out of the legacy structure into new modules covering core and profile-specific functions.

I am trying to add new code to a new folder `src/main/v2`, to which I have also added a `module-info.java` file. I have done the same for `v2-util`, which gives:

```
src/main/java/com/mycompany/MyClass.java
src/main/v2/com/mycompany/MyV2Class.java
src/main/v2/module-info.java
src/main/v2-util/com/mycompany/v2-util/MyV2UtilityClass.java
src/main/v2-util/module-info.java
pom.xml
```

**Note that `src/main/java` doesn't have a `module-info.java` file**. This is because the dependency graph for the legacy project is complicated and is full of things that become automatic modules or have split packages. Putting in place a `src/main/java/module-info.java` declaration has proved impossible and time-consuming, due mainly to split packages on third-party jars from the same provider.

Trying to compile the above structure works: Maven finds the new Java classes, but it seems that the `v2/module-info.java` declaration is forcing the compiler to insist on a module for the legacy stuff in `java/`. I'm seeing lots of "package X is declared in the unnamed module, but module X does not read it", meaning the build fails.

What I want to happen is that new code in module `v2` above can access:

- anything in the legacy code
- only what is exposed by the `v2-util` module.

My guess is that I'm misunderstanding how the module system works, and what I want to do is impossible.

One important point: I haven't set up any kind of Maven module system, I have simply used the build-helper-maven-plugin to tell it about the new source folders.

What is the best way to proceed?

Comment: What tomcat version?

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the module-system either. From what I can tell is that the runtime is currently ignoring the module-system for the compatiblity-reasons. So lets check the compilation-process.

I have a spring (non-springboot) application and made some adjustments to the compiler in maven:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
(...)
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>--add-exports</arg>
                        <arg>java.base/sun.security.rsa=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>--add-exports</arg>
                        <arg>java.base/sun.security.util=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>--add-exports</arg>
                        <arg>java.base/sun.security.x509=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        <arg>--add-opens</arg>
                        <arg>java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

For libraries that was part of the JDK in the past and has been excluded from the JDK 9> there are module-replacement as official dependencies in maven (see [Replacements for deprecated JPMS modules with Java EE APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204141) ).

Make sure those module-replacements have the scope "provided" to avoid having classcastexceptions.