# java 17 migration pom dependency issue : org.glassfish.main.javaee-api

Tags: java, dependencies, pom.xml, java-17

I am migrating projects to java 17.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.main.javaee-api</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.jws</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I came to know that, ****the javax.*  packages are migrated to jakarta .*****  . So, the above mentioned dependency need to be changed. But am not able to find an alternate one in java 17. Please help.

Comment: have you tried googling for dependencies that contain the classes in that library?

Comment: yes, but am not able to find one

Comment: this might be of service: https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/java/migrate/jakarta/javaxwstojakartaws

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacements for deprecated JPMS modules with Java EE APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204141/replacements-for-deprecated-jpms-modules-with-java-ee-apis)